# C#: In what assembly is SHDocVw.WebBrowser_V1 defined?

Tags: c#, assemblies

It's used on several websites which all seem to assume the reader knows what to do to have this type available, but I have no clue.

Example site, see the first comment:
http://blogs.artinsoft.net/mrojas/archive/2008/09/18/newwindow2-events-in-the-c-webbrowsercontrol.aspx

Comment: Thank you! Both answer are equally right. I gave Hans Passant the answer though, I remember him from the msdn forums as nobugz where he has helped me before ;)

Comment: His answer was also more thorough.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's not an assembly, it's a COM component.  Project + Add Reference, Browse tab, select c:\windows\system32\shdocvw.dll.  In Windows 7 pick shdocvw.tlb in the same directory instead.  This generates the interop library for the COM component with the SHDocVw namespace.  WebBrowser_V1 is one of the types you'll get from that.

Comment: For future searchers: shdocvw.tlb was not in my Windows 7 install for some reason. However, importing the Microsoft Internet Controls COM reference got me access to SHDocVw.

Answer (score 23):

You can get it from the COM component list. The assembly name is "Microsoft Internet Controls".

1. Right click "References" of your project in Solution Explorer view
2. Click Add Reference
3. Go to COM section
4. Select Microsoft Internet Controls
5. Click OK

Answer (score 9):

Add a COM reference to c:\windows\system\shdocvw.dll

This will create a .NET reference Interop.shdocvw.dll (or something similar) that includes the appropriate types.